# scrollbar on a canvas with multiples frames in it

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

good evening,
I work in Python with sqlite to make a data base of many exercices (of math). By a search, I want to display all the exercices in a canvas with multiples frames (each frames contains an exercice with its image gif). So I made a scrollbar which seems to work fine. But, when I want to show all the exercices (85), it stops at the number 82  and I don't know why ... Is there a restriction for the number of widgets we can put in the frame ?
Here is a peace of my code (sorry for my bad english):

> ```
> class liste_exercices(Toplevel):
> def __init__(self,parent,liste_numeros):
> Toplevel.__init__(self,parent)
> self.parent=parent
> self.liste_numeros=liste_numeros
> self.geometry("1140x1080+800+0")
> # donne le titre de la fenêtre
> self.title("Nombre d' exercices trouvés : "+str(len(self.liste_numeros)))
> self.vsb=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL,width=20)
> self.vsb.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S)
> self.c=Canvas(self,width=1240,yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
> self.c.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="news")
> #on attache le canvas à la scrollbar
> self.vsb.config(command=self.c.yview)
> # make the canvas expandable
> self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
> self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
> self.fr=Frame(self.c)
> # on crée une fenêtre pour mettre le Frame self.fr dans le canvas self.c
> self.c.create_window(0,0,window=self.fr)
> global liste_choix_exercices
> liste_choix_exercices=[] ### liste vide des exercices de l'utilisateur
> self.afficher()
> ```

```
def afficher(self):
   r=0
   for self.i in range(len(self.liste_numeros)):
       r+=1
       print("j'affiche l'image self.i = ",self.liste_numeros[self.i])
       enonce_exercice(self.fr,self.liste_numeros[self.i]).grid(row=r)
   self.fr.update_idletasks()
   self.c.config(scrollregion=self.c.bbox(ALL))
```

enonce_exercice is a class that display the exercice's image.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a limit on the coordinate system inside the canvas. It sounds like you hit it.

Comment: Thanks. So is there any solution for what I want to do ? that is display ALL the images even if there is 100000 ones ....

Comment: In order to go deeper in help, could you provide a ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: No way to reproduce the observed limit (add of 1000 `class enonce_exercice(Canvas)` having a `Label`). Could you provide more detail about `enonce_exercice()` ?

Comment: I find a solution : I display only 20 exercices (its images) per pages, with a Button that enable to go to the next page and so on. And my code is too long to put it here .... thanks

Comment: enonce_exercice is a frame which display the image of an exercice .